# Using checkbox to filter one column in a table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, userform

I want to filter one column of a table but using checkbox in a userform, im using a "filter" command button

I'm using this code but i want that if there 2 or more selected checkbox both values appear on the table results

```
Dim str As String

If EXP1.Value = True Then str = "Aftermarket"
If EXP2.Value = True Then str = "Purchasing"
If EXP3.Value = True Then str = "Quality"

  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PEP").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Array _
        (str), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```vb
Dim str As String, sep As String, i As Long
    
    'pairs of checkbox and filter values
    arr = Array(EXP1, "Aftermarket", EXP2, "Purchasing", EXP3, "Quality")
    
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 2
        If arr(i).Value = True Then
            str = str & sep & arr(i + 1)  'add the filter value
            sep = "|"                     'populate after first value
        End If
    Next i
    
    'convert `str` to an array for filtering
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PEP").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, _
           Criteria1:=Split(str, "|"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Answer (score 0):

Add all selected options to a string and create an array from that:

```
Dim str As String

If EXP1.Value = True Then str = IIf(str="", "", ";") & "Aftermarket"
If EXP2.Value = True Then str = IIf(str="", "", ";") &"Purchasing"
If EXP3.Value = True Then str = IIf(str="", "", ";") &"Quality"

if str <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PEP").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=split(str, ";"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End If
```